# sed/awk: remove similar lines after first occurrence

Tags: sed, awk, duplicate

i have:

```
constant1apple_____constant2asdfkjo___constant3
constant1apple_____constant2fdlkjef___constant3
constant1watermelonconstant2sdlfkeio__constant3
constant1banana____constant2asdfoie___constant3
constant1apple_____constant2soeivmn___constant3
constant1orange____constant2vjflkdslj_constant3
constant1watermelonconstant2xcvlvdiosnconstant3
constant1orange____constant2wieonvow__constant3
constant1apple_____constant2woemnivoiwconstant3
```

i want to keep only the lines with the first occurrences of the fruit names

output should be like this:

```
constant1apple_____constant2asdfkjo___constant3
constant1watermelonconstant2sdlfkeio__constant3
constant1banana____constant2asdfoie___constant3
constant1orange____constant2vjflkdslj_constant3
```

important notes:

- the fruit names could be literally anything i don't know of but they all have the same length
- the random string following the fruit name could also be anything but also has a specific length

no idea how to do it

Comment: Is it always exactly four space-separated columns?

Comment: This would be trivial in Awk, but pretty hard in `sed`. Why exactly do you need specifically a `sed` solution?

Comment: @grawity no not at all just constant characters instead of spaces

Comment: @tripleee i have no knowledge as you can see on how to write a question for awk, i'll try and update the question anyway

Comment: I don't see any indication that you tried in `sed` either. Just trying to find out if the simple obvious answer would be acceptable. I see you already received one such answer. If that's not acceptable, please [edit] your question to explain why. (And if it is, probably explain that Awk solutions will be fine too.)

Comment: @tripleee i tried but the attempts were too miserable to mention in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit easier to do with awk (or perl, or most other languages which have associative arrays):

```
awk '!seen[substr($0, 10, 10)]++' input.txt

awk '{ fruit = substr($0, 10, 10); if (!seen[fruit]++) print }' input.txt
```

(awk scripts are structured like `match1 {code1} match2 {code2} ...` The first variant only specifies the match condition but not code, using the implicit default `{print;}`; the second variant does the opposite but achieves the same thing. Whatever is easier to work with.)

Here `seen` is an associative array (a dict / hashmap) which counts how many times the second field has been seen so far. For every line, `seen[x]++` increments the value held at `seen[x]` and returns the previous value at the same time. If the previous value was 0, that's the first time the fruit has been seen.

In this version, `substr(input, start, count)` is used to extract 10 characters from $0 (representing the whole line), starting at character 10. (In the previous version, the array key was `$2` for the second space-separated column.)

---

awk works well, but depending on how much filtering you're planning to do (if it's more than just extracting unique 2nd column), it might be better to already start with a more general-purpose language:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
seen = set()
for line in sys.stdin:
    fruit = line[9:19]
    if fruit not in seen:
        seen.add(fruit)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

---

Alternatively, if the names can safely be reordered, you can use `uniq` to deduplicate them:

```
cat input.txt | sort | uniq --skip-chars=9 --check-chars=10
```

And if you only need the fruit names themselves, ignoring the rest, you can do this by extracting the columns *first* and using `uniq` on what's left:

```
cat input.txt | cut -c 10-19 | sort | uniq

cat input.txt | sed -r 's/^.{9}(.{10}).*/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: sorry i updated the question, there are no spaces and there is a constant in between (in case the latter makes a difference)

Comment: Just adding `-F _` and examining `$1` instead of `$2` should fix it. But changing the question after receiving an answer is extremely bad form.

Comment: @tripleee: `-F _` would not work here, since it's just padding, not a separator. There's no guarantee that the 2nd field won't be filled to the maximum in some lines (and as a result would have no `_` padding at all).

Comment: @cablewelo2ma: The code only needs to know about field widths starting from the left. If you needed unique combinations of fields 2+4, that would make a difference. As long as you only need unique values from field 2 itself, then it doesn't matter what's to the right of it.

Comment: @grawity by "if the names can safely be reordered, you can use uniq" do you mean that this solution will just mess the order of the lines?

Comment: @grawity excellent work with awk but i find this explanation cryptic to understand, nevermind, probably i just suck at this

Comment: Maybe avoid the [useless uses of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) though.

Comment: @tripleee: [Declined.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689069)